# PDO - Insert large array to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I need some help to improve my current code. I have a huge array (about 20,000 objects inside it). The array looks like this:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Player Object
        (
            [name] => Aaron Flash
            [level] => 16
            [vocation] => Knight
            [world] => Amera
            [time] => 900000
            [online] => 1
        )

    [1] => Player Object
        (
            [name] => Abdala da Celulose
            [level] => 135
            [vocation] => Master Sorcerer
            [world] => Amera
            [time] => 900000
            [online] => 1
        )

    [2] => Player Object
        (
            [name] => Ahmudi Segarant
            [level] => 87
            [vocation] => Elite Knight
            [world] => Amera
            [time] => 900000
            [online] => 1
        )

    [3] => Player Object
        (
            [name] => Alaskyano
            [level] => 200
            [vocation] => Royal Paladin
            [world] => Amera
            [time] => 900000
            [online] => 1
        )

    [4] => Player Object
        (
            [name] => Aleechoito
            [level] => 22
            [vocation] => Knight
            [world] => Amera
            [time] => 900000
            [online] => 1
        )
```

And so on... with about 20,000 Player Object in total.

Now I want to insert them all in to my database. I'd like to find a way to not loop through all players. It is causing a lot of performance issues and it's almost killing my computer. I'd like to make it in a single query, all at once.

But how can I get the Player Object attributes, like the "name", "level" and "vocation" of each individual object without looping them through?

This is what my code looks like:

```
// Insert player list to database
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO players (name, level, vocation, world, month, today, online) VALUES (:name, :level, :vocation, :world, :time, :time, :online) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE level = :level, vocation = :vocation, world = :world, month = month + :time, today = today + :time, online = :online");

foreach ($players as $player) {
  $query = $sql->execute([
    ":name" => $player->name,
    ":level" => $player->level,
    ":vocation" => $player->vocation,
    ":world" => $player->world,
    ":time" => $player->time,
    ":online" => $player->online
  ]);
}
```

Because right now on that foreach at the bottom, it is looping through 20,000 player objects in my array, and getting their names/level/vocation/world and so on.

Is there a better way to do this?
My way of doing it can't be the best solution. I can hear my PC is working overload and it feels as if it's about to crash.

Comment: Without looping you can't do anything here.

Comment: So there is no quick way to grab the $player->name and such without looping through each? Can't I somehow tell it that ":name" should equal to the "name" inside each Player Object? Looping this is causing so much lag and performance issues.

Comment: You can get items via `[]` syntax but that doesn't help you much

Comment: Like: ":name" => $players['name'] ? (My array is called $players)

Comment: Like `$players[0]->name`

Comment: IMHO you're doing it correctly, but inserting 20,000 items is going to take time and resources no matter which way you try it. The only unknown at this point is if you're loading all 20k rows into memory before insertion [hello high memory use] or iterating through a file one at a time or with batched/buffered reads. [better]

Comment: The thing is, I plan to put this up on a website later on. And I doubt the hosting provider would be happy about me using so much resources. It takes a couple of minutes to run the query, and it's sitting at 100% resource use during those minutes. There must be some more efficient way of doing this type of stuff?

Comment: Have you considered using 'batched transactions'. Currently, I suspect it commits each row (autocommit)?. If you ue transactions and commit say, every few hundred rows, then you cut down the work the database has to do quite a lot. Worth a try? It isn't a lot of change to your code, just a count  - commit and start transaction inside the loop,  so is easy to try? It can be surprising ;-/

Comment: @rickastley X amount of work requires X amount of resources, and you're not going to be able to finagle your way around it. If you're worried about what your host thinks then you can always put in artificial delays to spread the resource usage over a longer timeframe, or just move to a better host/platform where you don't get in trouble for using the resources you pay for.

Comment: can you create a simple fiddle with some small example array data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I still doubt that transactions and/or batched inserts are a viable solution to your resource usage problem, they're still a better solution than preparing massive statements like Dave has suggested.

Give these a shot and see if they help.

The following assumes that PDO's error handling mode is set to throw exceptions. Eg: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` If, for some reason, you can't use Exception mode then you'll need to check the return of `execute()` each time and throw your own Exception.

Single transaction:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO players (name, level, vocation, world, month, today, online) VALUES (:name, :level, :vocation, :world, :time, :time, :online) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE level = :level, vocation = :vocation, world = :world, month = month + :time, today = today + :time, online = :online");

$db->beginTransaction();
try {
    foreach ($players as $player) {
        $sql->execute([
            ":name" => $player->name,
            ":level" => $player->level,
            ":vocation" => $player->vocation,
            ":world" => $player->world,
            ":time" => $player->time,
            ":online" => $player->online
        ]);
    }
    $db->commit();
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    $db->rollBack();
    // at this point you would want to implement some sort of error handling
    // or potentially re-throw the exception to be handled at a higher layer
}
```

Batched Transactions:

```
$batch_size = 1000;
for( $i=0,$c=count($players); $i<$c; $i+=$batch_size ) {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    try {
        for( $k=$i; $k<$c && $k<$i+$batch_size; $k++ ) {
            $player = $players[$k];
            $sql->execute([
                ":name" => $player->name,
                ":level" => $player->level,
                ":vocation" => $player->vocation,
                ":world" => $player->world,
                ":time" => $player->time,
                ":online" => $player->online
            ]);
        }
    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        $db->rollBack();
        // at this point you would want to implement some sort of error handling
        // or potentially re-throw the exception to be handled at a higher layer
        break;
    }
    $db->commit();
}
```

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply. I just tested it and HOLY SH*T!!!! You are a God. You are literally a God. Why is there such a massive performance difference while using the "beginTransaction"? It completed it all within seconds. 20,000 took only 2 or 3 seconds. Compared to my original code that would take well over 6 or 7 minutes. That is insanely quick and only went up to about 18% resource usage. My code would go up to the 90-95% range. God damn! I gotta take a look at the transaction manual in PHP. This blew my mind! THANK YOU A BUNCH!!

Comment: I took a spin over to a mysql channel on IRC and asked if transactions would help in a case like this and, from what I recall, with one large transaction mysql can potentially defer writes to Tlog, index, and data files until the end of the transaction. There was one caveat mentioned though, if the database is replicated large transactions can introduce replication lag as large as the time taken to complete the transaction. I wouldn't classify it as something to lose sleep over, but something to bear in mind nonetheless.

Comment: Also bear in mind that any error during the transaction that triggers `rollback()` while the transaction is open will undo all changes. As well, DDL changes [CREATE/ALTER/etc] will trigger an implicit commit in mysql.

Answer (score -1):

I think the biggest performance gain you will get is by not doing one query per insert, but doing a single query for all inserts.  Something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO players (name, level, vocation, world, month, today, online) VALUES ";
$inserts = [];
$values = [];
$idx = 0;
foreach ($players as $player) {
    $idx++;
    $inserts[] = "(:name{$idx}, :level{$idx}, :vocation{$idx}, :world{$idx}, :month{$idx}, :today{$idx}, :online{$idx})";
    $values[":name{$idx}"] = $player->name;
    $values[":level{$idx}"] = $player->level;
    $values[":vocation{$idx}"] = $player->vocation;
    $values[":world{$idx}"] = $player->world;
    $values[":month{$idx}"] = $player->time;
    $values[":today{$idx}"] = $player->time;
    $values[":online{$idx}"] = $player->online;
}
$sql .= implode(",", $inserts);
$sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE level = VALUES(level), vocation = VALUES(vocation), world = VALUES(world), month = month + VALUES(time), today = today + VALUES(time), online = VALUES(online)";

$query = $db->prepare($sql)->execute($values);
```

Comment: That only inserted the last Player Object of the array. It ignored the rest.

Comment: Sorry was missing the `[]` after `$values` in the loop, just fixed it

Comment: `Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 75` line 75 is the `$query = $db->prepare($sql)->execute($values);`

Comment: Alright I guess php doesnt support named parameters on multi row inserts, you'll have to do question mark placeholders, but this should work now

Comment: Still the same error. Hmm... why would it try turn the array into a string?

Comment: Sweet fancy jesus ***NO***. This is an awful idea.

Comment: @Sammitch you think he'll get better performance doing 20,000 individual queries?  lol

Comment: It didn't insert anything this time. I might have to use my first method, but it's really killing the computer haha

Comment: Still doesn't insert anything. I'm about to give up xD

Comment: What if I try make it a JSON file and insert that instead? Anyone knows how to export it into JSON format from all the 20,000 player objects? And then save it as file.json, and then upload file.json to db? Would that work?

Comment: What I would do it dump the sql this is generating for an array of just like 4 players and see if it runs manually or what is going wrong.  This should work but I can't see what error messages you are getting or see the sql it is generating

Comment: @dave maybe you should read up on how prepared statements work.

Comment: @Sammitch maybe you should learn the basic of how databases work.  Try the first sentence here  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html

Comment: @dave once again I suggest reading up on how prepared statements work. Once `prepare()` is called steps 1 through 3 are already done and each `execute()` sends only the parameters. Programmatically constructing and executing a single prepared statement with 140,000 parameters is asinine, counter-productive, and bound to cause problems.

Comment: I am fully aware of how prepared statements work. I can basically guarantee you that in shared hosting auto commit is on, so each insert is going to be it's own transaction.  If you do one insert per row, you're going to be committing a transaction for each row.  That means that the server needs to sync some data to disc for EVERY ROW.   The network overhead is what is killing his speed.  If you think your way will be faster "because prepared statements" then you are simply wrong.  Yes, they are fast.  No, they are not going to make up for 20,000 round trips to the database.

Comment: So then show him how to do something *sane* like batched inserts in transactions, not ludicrous BS like this.

Comment: @Sammitch that's how the answer started and he couldn't get it working, so we worked backwards to this. Why don't YOU do that and actually be helpful though?